# Página das eleições mostra as medalhas sem tradução

Tags: bug, status-aceito, eleição

Nessa página: http://elections.stackexchange.com/#pt.stackoverflow as medalhas não estão traduzidas, o resultado disso é que elas aparecem como não concedidas aos candidatos que já as conquistaram, como por exemplo na imagem abaixo:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Uma possível solução é o patch desenvolvido pelo @bfavaretto:

```
StackElections.init({
   apikey: 'LYwuXpduJM2Kk9Twsc008w((',
   selectedBadges: ['Representante', 'Dever cívico', 'Convenção', 'Strunk & White', 'Eleitorado', 'Espírito Esportivo', 'Conhecedor', 'Copidesque', 'Tagarela'], badges: [{"rank":"silver","description":"Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation","name":"Yearling"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Use the maximum 40 votes in a day","name":"Vox Populi"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total","name":"Unsung Hero"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week","name":"Tumbleweed"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total","name":"Tenacious"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Answer a question with score of 1 or more","name":"Teacher"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Create a tag used by 50 questions","name":"Taxonomist"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Post 10 messages, with 1 or more starred, in <a href=\"http://chat.stackoverflow.com\">chat</a>","name":"Talkative"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First tag wiki edit","name":"Tag Editor"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First approved <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms\">tag synonym</a>","name":"Synonymizer"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First up vote","name":"Supporter"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Use 30 votes in a day","name":"Suffrage"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First question with score of 1 or more","name":"Student"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Edit 80 posts","name":"Strunk & White"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Complete at least 1,000 <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/review\">review</a> tasks. This badge is awarded once per review type","name":"Steward"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Question favorited by 100 users","name":"Stellar Question"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Up vote 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score","name":"Espírito Esportivo"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Ask a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintain a positive question record","name":"Socratic"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Served as an elected moderator for at least 1 year","name":"Sheriff"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Answer your own question with score of 3 or more","name":"Self-Learner"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Ask a question and accept an answer","name":"Scholar"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Answer more than 30 days after a question was asked as first answer scoring 2 or more","name":"Revival"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Complete at least 250 <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/review\">review</a> tasks. This badge is awarded once per review type","name":"Reviewer"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Provide an answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score","name":"Reversal"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Edit 50 tag wikis","name":"Research Assistant"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First improvement request","name":"Renovator"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Edit and answer 50 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score &gt; 0)","name":"Refiner"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"One post with score of 2 on <a href=\"http://meta.stackoverflow.com\">meta</a>","name":"Quorum"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Leave 10 comments with score of 5 or more","name":"Conhecedor"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Share a link to a question later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses","name":"Publicist"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Approve or reject 100 suggested edits","name":"Proofreader"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First bounty you offer on your own question","name":"Promoter"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First topic request to either be upvoted by others or to have a topic created from it","name":"Primer"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Followed the <a href=\"http://area51.stackexchange.com/\">Area 51</a> proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase","name":"Precognitive"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x","name":"Populist"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Question with 1,000 views","name":"Popular Question"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First review of someone else&#39;s proposed change","name":"Peer Review"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Delete own post with score of -3 or lower","name":"Peer Pressure"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Post 10 messages in <a href=\"http://chat.stackoverflow.com\">chat</a> starred by 10 different users","name":"Tagarela"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First retag","name":"Organizer"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Question with 2,500 views","name":"Notable Question"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Question score of 10 or more","name":"Nice Question"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Answer score of 10 or more","name":"Nice Answer"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Answer a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more","name":"Necromancer"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Earn at least 200 reputation (the <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation\">daily maximum</a>) in a single day","name":"Mortarboard"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Raise 500 helpful flags","name":"Marshal"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Earn 200 daily reputation 150 times","name":"Legendary"},{"rank":"silver","description":"First proposed change to be approved by others that handles others&#39; improvement requests","name":"Knowledgeable"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First bounty you offer on another person&#39;s question","name":"Investor"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Ask a well-received question on 30 separate days, and maintain a positive question record","name":"Inquisitive"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Read the entire <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/tour\">tour</a> page","name":"Informed"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First proposed change to be approved by others","name":"Incrementalist"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score &gt; 0)","name":"Illuminator"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Accepted answer and score of 40 or more","name":"Guru"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Question score of 100 or more","name":"Great Question"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Answer score of 100 or more","name":"Great Answer"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Question score of 25 or more","name":"Good Question"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Answer score of 25 or more","name":"Good Answer"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Provide non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags","name":"Generalist"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Question favorited by 25 users","name":"Favorite Question"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Visit the site each day for 100 consecutive days. (Days are counted in <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time\" rel=\"nofollow\">UTC</a>.)","name":"Fanatic"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Question with 10,000 views","name":"Famous Question"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Edit and answer 1 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score &gt; 0)","name":"Explainer"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Edit first post that was inactive for 6 months","name":"Excavator"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Earn 200 daily reputation 50 times","name":"Epic"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Visit the site each day for 30 consecutive days. (Days are counted in <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time\" rel=\"nofollow\">UTC</a>.)","name":"Enthusiast"},{"rank":"silver","description":"First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more","name":"Enlightened"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions","name":"Eleitorado"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Read the <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation\">documentation tour</a>","name":"Educated"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First edit","name":"Editor"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Delete own post with score of 3 or higher","name":"Disciplined"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Raise 80 helpful flags","name":"Representante"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Complete at least one <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/review\">review</a> task. This badge is awarded once per review type","name":"Custodian"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record","name":"Curious"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First down vote","name":"Critic"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First citation of a topic or example you haven&#39;t contributed to, in an answer you posted","name":"Creditor"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Edit 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts and tag edits)","name":"Copidesque"},{"rank":"silver","description":"10 posts with score of 2 on <a href=\"http://meta.stackoverflow.com\">meta</a>","name":"Convenção"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Vote for a candidate in the final phase of an <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/election\">election</a>","name":"Constituent"},{"rank":"gold","description":"Served as a pro-tem moderator for at least 1 year or through site graduation","name":"Constable"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Leave 10 comments","name":"Commentator"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First rollback","name":"Cleanup"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Vote 300 or more times","name":"Dever cívico"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First flagged post","name":"Citizen Patrol"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Visit an <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/election\">election</a> during any phase of an active election and have enough reputation to cast a vote","name":"Caucus"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Share a link to a question later visited by 300 unique IP addresses","name":"Booster"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First citation of a topic or example you&#39;ve contributed to","name":"Bluebook"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Voted 10 times, added 3 posts score &gt; 0, and visited the site on 3 separate days during the private beta","name":"Beta"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First bounty you manually award on your own question","name":"Benefactor"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First example up vote","name":"Backer"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Complete &quot;About Me&quot; section of user profile","name":"Autobiographer"},{"rank":"silver","description":"Edit 100 posts that were inactive for 6 months","name":"Archaeologist"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Share a link to a question later visited by 25 unique IP addresses","name":"Announcer"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"Visited every section of the FAQ (retired)","name":"Analytical"},{"rank":"bronze","description":"First bounty you manually award on another person&#39;s question","name":"Altruist"}]
});
```

Fonte: https://gist.github.com/bfavaretto/a18793ee38793e82932888a9558e92df

Ao rodar o código acima na console do browser dá para ver o problema corrigido:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Seria legal que corrigissem esse bug o mais rápido possível para termos uma análise mais apropriada dos nossos candidatos para essa eleição.

Comment: Bem, na eleição passada alguém já tinha relatado isso. Essa página foi criada por Yi Jiang e Tim Stone, tal como está na descrição (e a SE apenas a hospeda, eu acho). Localizei um post de cada um deles e deixei um comentário para cada com um link para cá.

Comment: Obrigado pelo patch @bfavaretto  =D

Answer (score 4):

Conversei com o Tim Stone do problema, e a solução proposta pelo @bfavaretto. Ele está ciente do que está acontecendo e prometeu resolver tudo assim que possível.

Comment: Boa. Diz pra ele que pode ignorar a tradução das descrições (como eu fiz), se os nomes forem traduzidos já resolve.

Comment: @bfavaretto Foi avisado já. Agora só falta esperar...